# Mvvmcross tombstoning - always return null values

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I tried two approaches:

1.

```
    public class SavedState
    {
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
    }

    public void ReloadState(SavedState state)
    {
        //Data1 and Data2 always have null values.
    }

    public SavedState SaveState() {
        return new SavedState
        {
            Data1 = "AAAA",
            Data2 = "BBBB"
        };
    }
```

2.

```
    protected override void ReloadFromBundle(IMvxBundle state)
    {
        base.ReloadFromBundle(state);

        //state.Data has 0 elements.
    }

    protected override void SaveStateToBundle(IMvxBundle bundle)
    {
        bundle.Data["Data1"] = "AAAA";
        bundle.Data["Data2"] = "BBBB";

        base.SaveStateToBundle(bundle);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? The ReloadStateand ReloadFromBundle methods are called but with null parameters. 
I have only Windows Store target, with custom presenter which shows view this way:

```
_rootFrame.Navigate(GetViewType(request), request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I had similar issue.

I used this code to show ViewModel with parameter:

```
ShowViewModel<UserAccountViewModel>(new UserAccountViewModelParams{ FromLogin = true });
```

and tombstoning behaved exactly like in your case.

When I changed it to:

```
ShowViewModel<UserAccountViewModel>();
```

it worked.

I guess it's MVX error.